# Attempting to verify if real roots of a polynomial produce the value "true" when plugged back in

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

Given the polynomial

```
poly = 1-6 x-3 x^4+x^7
```

and having already found the list of real roots, I now need to Check that the numerical values in the list `listreal` of real roots do correspond to the roots of `poly`, by producing the  truth values TRUE for the equation poly=0. If the TRUE values cannot be produced then explain why, and check the validity of the roots in the listreal by any other method if possible.

I tried using this:

```
(poly /. x -> listreal) === (poly = 0)
```

and it returned false which I believe is what I am looking for, although I am not sure that this is the right format, and I don't know any other way to check the validity of the roots.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you, you could do

```
poly = 1 - 6 x - 3 x^4 + x^7
sol = Solve[poly == 0, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
sol = poly /. sol // N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Chop[sol]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
PossibleZeroQ[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Here are alternative ways to write it thanks to suggestions in comments below

### variation 1

```
poly = 1 - 6 x - 3 x^4 + x^7
sol = Solve[poly == 0, x]
PossibleZeroQ@Chop[poly /. sol]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
And @@ %
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### variation 2

```
poly = 1 - 6 x - 3 x^4 + x^7
sol = Solve[poly == 0, x]
And @@ (poly == 0 /. sol // Simplify)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hi Nasser, may i suggest you add listreal = x /. Solve[poly == 0, x, Reals]//N instad of sol to keep it in line with the variable in the question? PossibleZeroQ is a lovely function btw.

Comment: `And @@ (poly == 0 /. sol // Simplify)` evaluates to `True` indicating that all solved values are exact roots.

Comment: I actually like the `PossibleZeroQ` solution. Could perhaps do
`PossibleZeroQ@Chop[poly /. x -> listreal]`?

Answer (score 2):

[`RootReduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootReduce.html) does this: from the documentation,

> `RootReduce[expr]` attempts to reduce `expr` to a single [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) object.

In this case, the single `Root` object can easily seen to be zero:

```
poly = 1 - 6 x - 3 x^4 + x^7;
listreal = Solve[poly == 0, x, Reals]
(*    {x -> -1.15..., x -> 0.166..., x -> 1.62...}    *)

RootReduce[poly /. listreal]
(*    {0, 0, 0}    *)
```